# Custom AWS compatible endpoing in goaws/JuJU

Tags: juju

I'm trying to add a custom endpoint (for eucalyptus) by modifying aws.go, but when running juju bootstrap, I get the error:  ERROR index file has no data for cloud {emea-az-1 http://109.104.120.3:8773/services/compute} not found

what other files do I need to modify test this?